# System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: property not found on object

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

Many apologies to add to the massive list of similar binding error questions out there, but after hours of searching I can't find a solution that will work for me!

I am trying to test a ViewModel in WPF, but the ICommand Button code is causing the standard binding error:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'CheckforNewHubs' property not found on 'object' ''HubManagerViewModel' (HashCode=13328197)'. BindingExpression:Path=CheckforNewHubs; DataItem='HubManagerViewModel' (HashCode=13328197); target element is 'Button' (Name='CheckForNewHubsButton'); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')

my command (in HubManagerViewModel) is:

```
public ICommand CheckForNewHubs
{
    get
    {
        return new RelayCommand(this.CheckForNewHubsExecute, this.CanSendHubManagerCommands);
    }
    set { }
}
```

and my DataContext is initiated in an XAML grid as:

```
<Grid.DataContext>
    <ViewModels:HubManagerViewModel/>
</Grid.DataContext>
```

I have tried explicitly setting the dataContext of the button like this:

```
<Button.DataContext>
    <ViewModels:HubManagerViewModel/>
</Button.DataContext>
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? At this point I'm just desperate for some new insight.

Thanks for your time in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have used Binding Path `CheckforNewHubs` but it should be `CheckForNewHubs`.